# Find a hash function to malfunction insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, hash, insertion-sort

Below is the original pseudocode for Insertion Sort:

```
function INSERTIONSORT(A[0..n−1])
for i←1 to n−1 do 
    j←i−1 
    while j≥0 and A[j+1]<A[j] do 
          SWAP(A[j+1],A[j]) 
          j←j−1
```

A company is using Insertion Sort inside one of their products. You are a cybersecurity expert that was hired by this company to assess any security flaws with their code. After a few tries, you managed to attack their Insertion Sort code and modify it in the following way:

```
function INSERTIONSORT(A[0..n−1])
         for i←1 to n−1 do
         j←i−1 
         while j≥0 and HASH(A,j+1) < HASH(A,j) do 
               SWAP(A[j+1],A[j])
               j←j−1
```

In other words, instead of indexing the array as A[j] and A[j+1]inside the “while” condition, you now have a hash function that takes the array and a index as the arguments and return an integer. Your job is to implement specific hash functions that will cause the algorithm to malfunction in different ways.

- a) Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to keep the original array unchanged. Explain why your solution works.
- b) Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to always run in the worst case complexity, even if the resulting array does not end up getting sorted. Explain why your solution works.
- c) Implement a hash function that causes Insertion Sort to sort the array in reverse. Explain why your solution works.

I think (a) and (b) is hash(A,j)=j and hash(A,j)=-j, but have no idea if that is correct and have no clue to c.

Comment: Your answers to (a) and (b) seem correct. I'd say the answer to (c) is `hash(A,j) = -A[j]`

Comment: hi, that seems not correct to me. For example, if original array is 5,4,3,6,1, then correct insertion sort will be 1,3,4,5,6, but hash insertion sort will be 6,5,4,3,1, but it should reverse the array, then correct answer should be 1,6,3,4,5

Comment: Ah, your interpretation of the question is different than mine. There's a subtle difference between *"sort the array in reverse"* and *"reverse the array"*. I expected the correct answer to be `6,5,4,3,1`

Comment: Then, any idea to this question?lol

Comment: This is a bubble sort, not an insertion sort. Sedgewick chapter 8. Stop reposting this question.

Comment: NO, IT IS NOT!!!

Comment: Robert Sedgewick doesn't agree with you, nor Donald E. Knuth, nor I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part a) Original array unchanged

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int hash(int arr[], int i) {
    return i;
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 1 ; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i-1;
            while ( j >= 0 && hash(arr, j+1) < hash(arr, j))
            {           
                temp     = arr[j];
                arr[j]   = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[] = {5, 6, 7, 3, 2 , 9, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    printf("Original array unchanged:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Part b) Worst Case insertion sort

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int hash(int arr[], int i) {
    return -i;
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 1 ; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i-1;
            while ( j >= 0 && hash(arr, j+1) < hash(arr, j))
            {           
                temp     = arr[j];
                arr[j]   = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[] = {5, 6, 7, 3, 2 , 9, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    printf("In worst case(number of swaps maximum)\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Part c) Sorted in reverse order.**

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int hash(int arr[], int i) {
    return -arr[i];
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 1 ; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i-1;
            while ( j >= 0 && hash(arr, j+1) < hash(arr, j))
            {           
                temp     = arr[j];
                arr[j]   = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[] = {5, 6, 7, 3, 2 , 9, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    printf("Sorted in reverse order:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```